# jQuery: detect if mouseover hidden element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a troll website for fun [(click here to see it)](http://thebutton.codehs.me), and I want the button to only appear when the mouse is not over the button. However, jQuery's "mouseover" action does not detect if your cursor is over a hidden element. Is there any way I can accomplish this with a different action, or do I have to do something to the button with HTML?

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#button").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#button").hide();
    });
    $("#button").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#button").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could be a multitude of things. Can you post some code and maybe a picture of what is going on? It could be that the element is being covered by another transparent element. Seems to be working in Chrome

Comment: How can your mouse be over a hidden element? There is nothing to be over.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#button:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text<br/>
  
  <button id="button" onclick="return false;">And a jumpy button</button><br/>
  
  Followed by more text
</p>
```

Comment: You should also add `pointer-events: none;` so that click/selection events won't trigger on the element

Comment: @DrifterSheep it's CSS.

Comment: @AlonEitan, I wasn't sure if the OP wants the invisible button be clickable or not, but yes, we could also do that, or just the old fashioned `return false` thing.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, because it makes the button flicker on hover

Answer (score 0):

The `.hide()` and `.show()` methods sets the CSS `display:none` setting. This makes the element unhoverable (if exists such word :D), so, you need to set the visibility of the element instead:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#button").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#button").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("#button").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#button").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```